# How to save Credit card with Paypal without Paypal account?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I need to implement the payment transactions with paypal account and credit/debit card using paypal on my mobile application (Android and iOS SDK's).

In one hand I understand the part of having a paypal account and paying with it, but in the other hand I took a look at Uber and I found that the users can save their credit card without creating a paypal account. How can I achieve this behavior? Do I have to save this credit cards on my server? or is this a feature of Paypal?

PD: I already know Uber uses BrainTree, but I have seen the same feature on other apps with Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "reference transactions" or "vaulted credit cards".  PayPal saves the card data on their server, and then you just save the transaction ID on your server.  When you submit a reference transaction request you just include the transaction ID from the original transaction you processed (could be an Auth or Sale transaction) along with the new amount you need to process.

Depending on what you're using to process the cards, though, the API you would use for the reference / vaulted transaction would be different.

If you're using Payments Pro you would be using either [DoDirectPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) / [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) or the [PayFlow](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#pf) API setup as a [reference transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#example-reference-transaction).

If you're working with REST that's where the [vaulted transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/) would come into play.

Comment: Thnk you for your answer, but do i have to create an user account for each user to save their credit cards? or the vaulted transactions will handle that for me?

Comment: The vaulted transaction will handle that for you.

Comment: Well, that said, you might need a user account so that you pull the related transaction ID from the original setup.  That's up to your how you're storing data in your db.

Comment: So, lets put an example: When i create an Uber account from the Android application. It actually creates on the backend an Uber account and a PayPal account? If that's the case, on this new PayPal account it saves the user credit cards?

Comment: I did not design user's system, of course, but the standard procedure would be a user account created in the app system, which would then get a user ID associated with it.  You might then have a related "payments" table where you save all payments related to any given user.  This way you could then pull the transaction ID from a payment out based on the user ID, and by passing that transaction ID into a reference transaction request with PayPal they would use the same billing information that was associated with that original transaction to process the new amount.